# Cordova aap version plugin is not working

Tags: cordova

I am developing a hybrid android app in which the app version plugin is not working.I have removed the plugin and reinstall through CLI.How can i fix the issue.Can anybody please answer ?

Comment: do you any have logs ?  what are version of cordova and plugin please

Comment: Hello Balaji, welcome to StackOverflow. FYI no one here is a magician. Your question needs much more details if you want to get any help. What have you tried exactly, what "not working" means etc. Please revise your question.